# Real analysis: convergence question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I found the closed formula for the sum of 1/( k^2+3k+2) from 1 to infinity which is 1/2 - 1/(n+2). Could you first check whether this is right. If so, how to find the sum of this series? Is it just set lim n goes to infinity then we have 1/2 as the sum of the series?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct that the sum of the first $n$ terms is $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n + 2}$; that is,

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k^2 + 3k + 2} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n + 2}$$

Taking a limit as $n \to \infty$, we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2 + 3k + 2} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n + 2}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n + 2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - 0
\end{align*}